# What is the difference between a shim and a polyfill?

Tags: terminology, naming, vocabulary, polyfills, shim

Both seem to be used in web development circles, see e.g. [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills), which says:

> So here we're collecting all the shims, fallbacks, and polyfills...

Or, there's the [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/) project.

In my current project we're using a number of these, and I want to stick them all in the same directory. So, what should I call this directory---`shims`, or `polyfills`?

Comment: reopen: I suppose "what should I call this directory" could be opinion-based, but it really isn't given the larger context of the question -- nor is that the most important aspect of this question.  All of the answers here seem to be in agreement, and there is significant use of facts, references, and specific expertise.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

- A **shim** is any piece of code that performs interception of an API call and provides a layer of abstraction. It isn't necessarily restricted to a web application or HTML5/CSS3.
- A **polyfill** is a *type of shim* that retrofits legacy browsers with modern HTML5/CSS3 features usually using Javascript or Flash.

Answering your specific question, call your directory `shims` if you want to keep the directory generic.

Answer (score 301):

**Shim**

If you are familiar with the adapter pattern, then you know what a shim is. Shims intercept API calls and create an abstract layer between the caller and the target. Typically shims are used for backward compatibility. For instance the *es5-shim* npm package will let you write ECMAScript 5 (ES5) syntax and not care if the browser is running ES5 or not. Take *Date.now* as an example. This is a new function in ES5 where the syntax in ES3 would be *new Date().getTime()*. If you use the *es5-shim* you can write *Date.now* and if the browser you’re running in supports ES5 it will just run. However, if the browser is running the ES3 engine *es5-shim* will intercept the call to *Date.now* and just return *new Date().getTime()* instead. This interception is called shimming. The relevant source code from es5-shim looks like this:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    };
}
```

**Polyfill**

Polyfilling is really just a specialized version of shimming. Polyfill is about implementing missing features in an API, whereas a shim wouldn’t necessarily be as much about implementing missing features as it is about correcting features. I know these seems overly vague, but where shims are used as a more broader term, polyfill is used to describe shims that provide backward compatibility for older browsers. **So while shims are used for covering up old sins, polyfills are used for bringing future enhancements back in time.**
As an example there is no support for sessionStorage in IE7, but the polyfill in the *sessionstorage* npm package will add this feature in IE7 (and older) by using techniques like storing data in the name property of the window or by using cookies.

Comment: ***So while shims are used for covering up old sins, polyfills are used for bringing future enhancements back in time.*** This sums up everything to me. Thank you for a clear explanation.

Comment: This answer is helpful, thanks. But it seems to me that the two terms often aren't used precisely on the web, including es5-shim. I think es5-shim is a mix of shims and polyfills by your definition.

Comment: The Date-Example looks like a Polyfill to me. Why I think it is a Polyfill? Because Date.now is a native call. A Polyfill will add that feature with the same API seamless to the Browser.

A shim comes with a new API like: `MyShim.Date.now();`

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 103):

From what I understand:

A polyfill is code that detects if a certain "expected" API is missing and manually implements it. E.g.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { Function.prototype.bind = ...; }
```

A shim is code that intercepts existing API calls and implements different behavior. The idea here is to normalize certain APIs across different environments. So, if two browsers implement the same API differently, you could intercept the API calls in one of those browsers and make its behavior align with the other browser. Or, if a browser has a bug in one of its APIs, you could again intercept calls to that API, and then circumvent the bug.

Answer (score 69):

Citing [Axel Rauschmayer](http://rauschma.de/) from his book [*Speaking JavaScript*](http://speakingjs.com/):

> - A shim is a library that brings a new API to an older environment, using
>     only the means of that environment.
> - A polyfill is a shim for a browser API. It typically checks if a browser
>     supports an API. If it doesn’t, the polyfill installs its own
>     implementation. That allows you to use the API in either case. The
>     term polyfill comes from a home improvement product; according to [Remy
>     Sharp](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/):
>
> > *Polyfilla is a UK product known as Spackling Paste in the US. With that in mind: think of the browsers as a wall with cracks in it. These
> >     [polyfills] help smooth out the cracks and give us a nice smooth wall
> >     of browsers to work with.*

Answer (score 9):

A fantastic article written about this from a few years back that explains this well:

[What is a Polyfill?](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill)

In the article the (2) are simply contrasted as such:

**Shim:** a piece of code that you could add (i.e. `JavaScript`) that would fix some functionality, but it would most often have ***it's own API***.

**Polyfill:** something you could drop in (i.e. `JavaScript`) and it would silently work to mimic ***existing browser APIs*** that are otherwise unsupported.

Comment: I think this is a misleading representation of both the common usage and what Remy Sharp actually says in blog post you've linked to. *Shim* is most often used synonymously with *polyfill* nowadays (see particularly the [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim)) and Remy is particular about saying that *to him* the word 'shim' alluded to a custom API (by comparison with `shim.gif`). He is very much not dictating that the words be used in this way, and by saying *"to me"* he is tacitly acknowledging that his usage is not universal.

Answer (score 2):

Polyfill is just a script that will check a certain API existence in the browser, ok?
If the API doesn't exist in the browser polyfill(which is a simple script) will act something like this:

for example, I'm gonna use Bluetooth API in the browser and I know some browser doesn't have such API so I will write something like this in order to check my API existence:

```
if(!navigator.bluetooth) { // write polyfill here }
```

Shim is a script as well which mostly provided as a plugin or library and how it works?

Actually, it will override an already existing API and implements a different behavior in order to support new APIs in older browsers.
It worth noting that Shims mostly are used for backward compatibility.