# where does angular fit in the context of web-component initiatives like mozilla brick and google's polymer?

Tags: angularjs, web-component

There is an obvious parallel between Angular's directives and 'web-components', although I'm not sure if Angular is leveraging the shadow-dom in the same way.
I guess I'm wondering how angular will evolve to support or enhance the notion of web-components in the upcoming years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to Mozilla Brick, but Polymer is really a set of polyfills to transform existing browsers to use the next generation specs.

The Angular team has stated that they expect the state of Web Components to be completely compatible with Angular 2.0.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/4RSYaKmbtEk/uYnY3900wpIJ

Comment: I can speak to Brick --> the Brick UI components are built with X-Tag, a Web Components library that shares the same underlying polyfills that Polymer uses.

Comment: See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089075/what-is-the-difference-between-polymer-elements-and-angularjs-directives