# Difference between Angular Dart and Polymer Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

Angular gives you the possibility of dynamic two-way-data-binding. But it allows you also to create custom elements and directives.

So, if I use Angular in Dart, there is no need for Polymer any more, is it right?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/web-ui/2tMZ6Hp4J1o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a recent demo that shows how to combine Polymer's elements with Angular for routing and other app logic.

It looks fun, but I am not sure whether as of today the generated js code size is reasonable enough.

https://github.com/sethladd/dart-angular-polymer-data-binding

Slides for an accompanying talk: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3tMhVSd9MFIV0xfRm5NZ0VpNzg/edit 

Blog with a summary: http://blog.sethladd.com/2014/02/angular-and-polymer-data-binding.html

Slide 66:
[image: Comparison of Angular and Polymer features]

Comment: This diagram seems to suggest that these are two complementary technologies.  Angular provides ways to make Components which as far as I can see are same-enough to Elements.  There are Templates in Angular which look like Layouts to me.  I think the this picture should come after one comparing the two with areas of overlap and contention.

Comment: @will I agree that my answer does not really answer the question and more thorough explanation is need and the diagram is somewhat misleading. My take is that from the programmers perspective, regarding what each of the tools aims to accomplish, Polymer is a subset of Angular. Yes, Polymer is more full featured in what it does, but Angular does basically what Polymer does, and a lot more regarding the higher level app functionality. A possible future is that Angular will… well, they discuss it here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular-dart/JY8b15-KG4Q/618z3qvAIegJ

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the discussion referenced by @Paul Collingwood which contains a good explanation.
This similar question has an extensive explanation: [What is the difference between Polymer elements and AngularJS directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089075)