# Polymer Elements vs Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

I know that this has been asked previously, most notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089075/what-is-the-difference-between-polymer-elements-and-angularjs-directives/18092637#18092637).

However, the answers seem to me quite abstract and I find my self quite confused in practice.

The .vs answer seem to be:

> Polymer (and more correctly, Shadow DOM) create the ability to not
>   only compose bits of HTML, but to encapsulate them as well. This is a
>   fundamentally new capability and one that can be used with any other
>   templating system or framework to enhance their power.

Which doesn't really tell me all that much, as far as I understand angular directives do pretty much the same thing in practice, although polymer elements might be a bit more efficient performance wise. I'm sure that "encapsulate" has some kind of deeper meaning here in this context that I am not comprehending.

Let's say I'm developing an AngularJS web application. When, how and why would I use polymer elements over angular directives?

Would polymer elements be used **instead of** angular directives, if so when would one use one over the other? Or would angular directives be implemented **in terms of** polymer elements?

Answer (score 32):

You're really asking two different things, "What's the differences when implementing/building components vs. using one?"

### Consuming components

In the foreseeable future, you **use both together**. It doesn't matter what technology/library a web component is built with or what vendor makes it. Simply `bower install` (or similar) and *use* the components that make sense for your app.

What matters is that everything *will* be DOM, meaning elements will work seamlessly together. The interop story is great. Here's a POC of an Angular directive data-bound to a Polymer element: http://ebidel.github.io/polymer-experiments/polymer-and-angular/together/

---

### Building components

Building elements is a different story at the moment. Polymer's approach is to center itself around all things web components. Angular was built before the time of web components, so things are a bit different.

- Angular directives are a way to build custom tags/components. Polymer and the Custom elements specification is the standards-based way to do that.
- How you build a Polymer-element is *extremely* declarative. Angular directives are mostly defined in JS (with the ability to reference a template file).
- Because Polymer elements using Custom elements, inheritance is simple. I'm not sure of the inheritance story in Angular directives/
- Polymer elements use Shadow DOM. This gives them encapsulation of DOM and CSS. Styles you define in your element don't bleed out and page styles don't bleed in. I could be wrong, but Angular directives do not have any notion of style encapsulation. It's a hard problem that the Shadow DOM spec gives us for free.
- The data binding concepts are similar

> would angular directives be implemented in terms of polymer elements

- Eventually, Angular will adopt some of the evolving Web Component standards. This will be true for all frameworks. Ember just made [their 2014 plans known](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/12/17/whats-coming-in-ember-in-2014.html), which include web components. For example, Angular.dart already uses Shadow DOM for directives.
- Polymer elements (custom elements) are interoperable with other custom elements by default. This is because they're just DOM. DOM elements work well together :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So in summary, use Polymer Custom Elements instead of Angular Directives for building components and use Angular Directives just to add behavior to existing components?

Comment: The example linked doesn't seem to provide a true comparison (the Angular version has `id`s and `class`es for unclear reason.) Is there any simple example illustrating where code in `Polymer` is significantly shorter than in `Angular`?

Comment: @SvenMalvik The link doesn't work. But does from my email. I don't understand how one can make such a comparison using totally different components for different cases.