# Platform.js as a true Web Components shim (without Polymer)

Tags: firefox, polymer, web-component, shim

I've been really impressed by a couple of examples of 'raw' Web Components in the wild, most recently Addy Osmani's latest version of the TodoMVC, called Componentized Todo. Now, with Chrome 36 hitting stable, this example works *without* Polymer's platform.js shim (which is awesome!)

I wondered how easily, then, it would be to convert this project to use platform.js alone, and get it working on (at first) Firefox stable and (later) Safari, IE, mobiles etc. Because that sounds to me like a really big step forward for Web Components, when they become true extensions to browsers (either natively or through platform.js as a shim), rather than being tied to Polymer as a framework.

I added platform.js to that example and got this running, but couldn't access the `template` element in the individual files, so had to make some compromises. I've submitted this as a PR: https://github.com/addyosmani/componentized-todo/pull/1

My question is, is this a viable direction for platform.js to be taking - to be breaking beyond its role in Polymer and becoming truly a shim for Web Components in older browsers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945811/chrome-web-components-polymer-needed/24946385#24946385

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Shadow DOM with polyfills, platform.js and webcomponents.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203688/using-shadow-dom-with-polyfills-platform-js-and-webcomponents-js)