# Using Shadow DOM with polyfills, platform.js and webcomponents.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, shadow-dom

Currently Shadow DOM is supported by only Chrome and Opera (only webkit) and can be optionally enabled in Firefox, it can how ever be used in all browsers using webcomponents.js (https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/platform.html).

Is someone already using this? Is it 100% compatible with other non-supported browsers, any help would be appreciated.

(Ref link about shadow dom and webcompanents.js: http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-shadow-dom/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit or research I've found out Shadow DOM can be used in browsers IE10+, Chrome, firefox and safari using webcomponents.js