# Can we overwrite Javascript DOM object prototype properties?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have been looking for a way to permanently change the HTMLFormElement Javascript object's 'onsubmit' behavior. Let's suppose that one of my Javascript would contain the following code:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.onsubmit = function () {
    this.submit();
    // Make sure that you can only submit once.
    this.onsubmit = function () {
        return false;
    };
    return false;
};
```

The idea would be to simply prevent double submits on all forms of the document. I wasn't able to figure out how to do this since the above example is not working.

Is there a way to achieve this without looping through all existing HTMLElements after the document is loaded? A way which would be compatible with some older browser and also persist the behavior if you create new form elements using other scripts. (Vanilla JS only please)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just write code that doesn't submit your forms twice, instead of changing native prototypes ?

Comment: use event delegation to have a single document event hit all forms, no under-the-hood monkeying required.

Comment: @adeneo Actually this is a simplified example of something more complex which would require something similar to this to keep simple.

Comment: @dandavis Do you have some examples?

Comment: I tried and even multiple `.submit()` or clicking a submit button multiple times only submitted the form once.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("submit", function(e){ var el=e.target; if(el.spent) return e.preventDefault(); el.spent=true; })`

Comment: @dandavis Don't `return false` in an event listener, that's only for event handlers. Use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: How older is "compatible with some older browser"? Why do you have [ES6] tag if you want compatibility with older browsers? Are you trying to prevent form submission done by the user (through submit button or implicit submission), or done by you (through `.submit()`)? Are you using `target` in your form?

Comment: What about other scripts that use `form` elements? They most likely won't anticipate your default behavior.

Comment: What are you going to do if the form submit has failed? User cannot try to do it again. So, good practice in here is temporary to disable "submit" button and enable it after success send. It may be more complex and difficult but it really solves the problem instead of hiding only one effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we overwrite Javascript DOM object prototype properties?

Although the javascript spec cuts host objects a lot of slack in violating normal javascript behavior `Object.defineProperty(HTMLFormElement.prototype, "onsubmit", {get: () => {return false;}})` does work. "Work" as in setting a getter on the prototype.

But it's not actually what you want. That's just replacing the getter/setter functionality. There is no guarantee that the browser goes through the javascript inheritance chain to retrieve the handler for the current form.

Either because it bypasses javascript by directly looking at some underlying native properties or because it doesn't have to look at the prototype at all and looks at an instance property of the form itself.

Messing with prototypes is rarely a good idea if you don't know how and when individual properties are actually used by the target class.

Another thing: the getter/setter actually is on `HTMLElement.prototype`, not `HTMLFormElement.prototype`. At least that's where it is in Firefox. You should at least inspect the inheritance chain before trying to mess with it ;)

> The idea would be to simply prevent double submits on all forms of the document.

Instead of messing with prototypes you can simply install a capturing event listener on the document.

capturing because it happens earlier and is less likely to be intercepted via [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) without canceling the [default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), which would be the form submission this case.

```
document.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {e.preventDefault();}, true);
```

Comment: The submit event actually propagates to the document? I thought someone in comments claimed it does not, otherwise that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: By the way I tried the defineProperty trick on both Chrome and Firefox and it didn't seem to behave as expected. I'm not sure there is actually a way to get to what I was hoping without going through all elements. Also the event listener trick does not work in all browsers.

Comment: I said the prototype thing is not what you want, I just answered that part of the question first.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('form'), function(form) {
  form.onsubmit = function () {
    // Make sure that you can only submit once.
    this.onsubmit = function () {
      return false;
    };
    return true;
  };
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a way to avoid doing this :) Is there a way to predefine the 'onsubmit' action on all forms without going on them one by one?

Comment: Main reason why is if I go do var newForm= document.createElement('form'); The code below will need to be rerun on the new form only... not the best solution :(

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette have you looked at event delegation?

Comment: Submit events don't bubble though. jQuery has to hack in that functionality.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - oh, that's right, not all events bubble, only in jQuery magic land.

Comment: @dandavis I'll take a stab at your example, but do you know if this is compatible with IE9?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You can use event delegation on non-bubbling events by listening to capture instead of bubble. But `submit` seems to bubble, in fact.

Comment: IE9 yes (i think), IE8, needs attachEvent i think. i dunno, it's been so long since i cared...

Comment: @dandavis well it said "Bubbles: Yes (although specified as a simple event that doesn't bubble)"

Comment: But the point of this surely has to be to stop other event handlers, not the form submit itself, as that would reload the page, and only submit once anyway, and delegating the event and preventing default does not stop event handlers attached directly ?

Comment: @adeneo: the form could be `target`ed

Comment: @dandavis - well, okay, but does anyone really do that anymore ?

Comment: @adeneo: well, i `target` all the time to hack moodle into something that sucks less. i use it to hidden iframes a lot too in other projects. in all, id say maybe 40% of my forms are targeted.

Comment: @dandavis - I don't think I've ever added a target attribute to a form, like never ?

Comment: But if it does open in a different window, the delegated `preventDefault` would work.

Comment: @adeneo If you're working with iframes it becomes useful.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** Nope, do as @Louy says, it's correct. DOM was designed to be looped through, no worries.

---

Yeah, you can overwrite `HTMLElement` properties and it's same for `HTMLElement` descendants. But specifically for some properties, like event callbacks, you're not allowed to do that, because they are not normal properties but `getters` and `setters`. I get the following error for your code, which is probably what you meant by "*doesn't work*":

[image: image description]

Even if you achieved to do that, I'm not sure if the resulting behavior is defined by standards. I think this would definitely not lead to anything compatible between browsers.

My experience also shows that globally changing some API because you need it for specific functions is not a good idea - soon your request might change and you will be changing whole API in general.

Comment: Again the concern was that if you create a new form (e.g.: var newForm= document.createElement('form');) you will have to re-apply the same logic if you want this behavior to be standard accross your site. This behavior was also very unintrusitve which is why I was looking for something simple. But thanks for the details, I understand at least why I cannot overwrite those properties!

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette Trust me, I thought hard before posting answer that doesn't fullfill your request. I like to say that in programming, nothing is impossible. Unfortunatelly, it's not 100% true.

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette, you can just as easily create a factory function that creates the `form` element and attach the listener, now you just call that function instead of `document.createElement('form')`.

Comment: @MinusFour Yes I have something like that in mind already - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MinusFour I also thought of proposing `.createElement` ovrriding. But there are other ways of creating elements, like parsing HTML (`x.innerHTML = "<form ...";`). So I concluded it's really hard to make a general reliable solution.

Comment: @TomášZato, you can also create a wrapper for that. Although I see your point, you'd have to anticipate every possible way to create the `form` element. Then again, it's only you who would need to deal with these custom functions, since it's you who is interested in overriding the defaults.

Comment: @MinusFour I feel strong urge to bet with you that you won't be able to override all the apis :) Also I have some performance concerns about overriding some of them. It's an interesting thing for fun, but definitelly not a good idea in serious business.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overwrite JavaScript DOM object prototype properties. However, you should never ever ever ever... EVER do this! That is, unless you're writing a [**polyfill**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5) that is supposed to add standard behavior so browsers that don't support it. Unless you're in that very specific and fairly rare situation, [**you're not supposed to ever modify objects you don’t own**](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)!

For your specific use case, you can easily achieve the desired effect by using `event.preventDefault()` on every click of the submit button except for the first click :

```
var alreadySubmitted = false;

document.getElementById("submitbutton").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if(!alreadySubmitted) {
        // The first time the button is clicked
        alreadySubmitted = true;
    } else {
        // All subsequent times the button is clicked
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```