# Website doesn't Work in IE8 but works in Google Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, yii

I have a sidebar in my website admin panel, I have made it in Yii Php Framework, but my website working fine in google chrome, mozilla, but when i use Internet Explorer 8... The sidebar in my website admin panel, doesnot appear.

How do i Fix this compatibility issue so it can work in IE8 too?

Here is my code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9] >
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif] -->
<?php
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE 10')) { ?>
    <link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/themes/mydesign/assetsadmin/global/css/ie10.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php   }
?>

<!--[if IE 9]>
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/themes/mydesign/assetsadmin/global/css/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/themes/mydesign/assetsadmin/global/css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of Internet Explorer have created endless, endless headaches for web designers over the years. [IE 8 was released in 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8), and some believe that supporting it is something [no one should ever have to do again](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). But it's still in use, and its [global market share](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) as of this writing is 5.95%.

If supporting IE 8 is important to you, then you'll need to do some debugging. For example, if a component isn't showing up, try removing the CSS styles from it and see if it shows up, then re-add the styles one by one.

I would also second the other recommendations here. Add support for HTML5 elements using [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), detect browser features using [modernizr](https://modernizr.com), and add [polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5) as needed.

Comment: I mostly use google chrome, but most of my clients use IE8, and sidebar doesnot show up to them. I will check these features modernize and polyfills

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the YII framework but the below code if for HTML5 support in IE8
If you don't have this code added already then add it to the `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) ?  Modernizr is a small piece of JavaScript code that automatically detects the availability of next-generation web technologies in your user's browsers.

Include the modernizer in your project and add the following

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html>

<head>
```

Comment: Yes, try that and let us know if that helped you.