# Why does Internet Explorer not support includes()?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, include, indexof

I am trying to support cross-browser compatibility, but the function includes() is not supported by IE ( Internet Explorer ). Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is part of the [ES7 (now ES2017)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2017/#sec-array.prototype.includes) and [ES6 (now ES2015)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.includes) javascript specification respectively.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer):

> Internet Explorer ... is a discontinued series of graphical web browsers

key word: *discontinued*. Microsoft only develops [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) now. IE may still get security updates but it will no longer received new javascript updates or any browser specification updates.

---

> `includes()` is not supporting in Internet Explorer , can you explain me why ?

Internet Explorer doesn't support `Array.prototype.includes` or `String.prototype.includes` because Microsoft no longer develops IE. Those specs came after Microsoft discontinued IE, therefore, it won't get those features.

BUT WAIT

You can still use new javascript in old browser by using [polyfills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5).

You can use [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) as a library of polyfills.

**To use `includes(...)` in IE, just include this at the top of of your `<head>` before any scripts**.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` was actually introduced by ES7.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support ES2016 and ES2016+ features because it is an outdated web browser that has been replaced by Microsoft Edge. Microsoft Edge is the modern web browser from Microsoft that supports the latest web standards and features, including ES2016 and ES2016+. It is recommended to use Microsoft Edge or other modern web browsers to ensure compatibility with the latest JavaScript features. If you need to support Internet Explorer for legacy reasons, you can use a transpiler like Babel to convert your ES2016 and ES2016+ code into ES5 code, which is compatible with Internet Explorer.