# window.showOpenFilePicker polyfill

Tags: javascript, file, polyfills

Is there a polyfill for `window.showOpenFilePicker` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker))?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of polyfills in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087331/what-is-the-meaning-of-polyfills-in-html5)

Comment: @Sapt-Programmer The OP does not appear to be asking about what polyfills are, they are asking if a polyfill exists for a specific function. That question is off-topic (as asking for off-site resources). The fact that they've answered their own question with such a polyfill does not excuse the poor question, just as the poor question does not excuse the poor answer.

Comment: Did you search check the docs? What did you search for?

Comment: Please share some code, that you have tried so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function showOpenFilePickerPolyfill(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "file";
        input.multiple = options.multiple;
        input.accept = options.types
            .map((type) => type.accept)
            .flatMap((inst) => Object.keys(inst).flatMap((key) => inst[key]))
            .join(",");

        input.addEventListener("change", () => {
            resolve(
                [...input.files].map((file) => {
                    return {
                        getFile: async () =>
                            new Promise((resolve) => {
                                resolve(file);
                            }),
                    };
                })
            );
        });

        input.click();
    });
}

if (typeof window.showOpenFilePicker !== 'function') {
    window.showOpenFilePicker = showOpenFilePickerPolyfill
}
```

Comment: For Typescript, just replace `(options: OpenFilePickerOptions)`