# What is a shim repository?

Tags: git, bower

In the context of web programming. What is a shim repository?

For instance, when I search "handlebars" in the bower package search page one of the result is:

"Shim repository for Handlebars.js"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a shim and a polyfill?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599815/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shim-and-a-polyfill)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think "shim repository" is a standardized term in web programming - its just how that specific project - the [Components project](https://github.com/components/components) - describes the repositories they create as stand-ins for those popular 3rd-party components.

Those repositories are "[shims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing))" in the sense that they adapt the releases of those popular components into a standard format needed by the Components project to support the package managers that the Components project targets.

Comment: So this means that if you are not using the components project for anything, these shim repositories are not useful? e.g. if I want to install font-awesome as a bower component and find this https://github.com/components/font-awesome ?