# Difference between "font-awesome" and "components-font-awesome"?

Tags: npm, font-awesome

Where is the difference between "font-awesome" and "components-font-awesome"?
Which of those should be preferred?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301475/what-is-a-shim-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Font-awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) is the original, well-known, suite of pictographic icons.

[Component-Font-Awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/components-font-awesome) is a shim repository (i.e. an adapted copy) of Font Awesome for the [Component project](https://github.com/components/components).

The goal of the Component project is to have a single shim repository for common projects such as Font Awesome supporting multiple package manager such as [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), [Bower](https://bower.io/), [Jam](https://hotframeworks.com/jamjs/), ...

To answer your question: Which of those should be preferred? I would say that if the original repository fulfil your needs, use it, otherwise try the shim repository.