# what is an inline helper, shim and polyfill in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, polyfills, shim

what is an inline helper, shim and polyfill in Javascript?

Could someone explain what they really mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "inline helper" is an extremely generic phrase that pretty much means what it says. For the difference between "shim" and "polyfill", consult [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599815/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shim-and-a-polyfill)

Comment: The standard does not define any of those. That means that terms can be treated differently depending on a particular community, development practices or products.